# Android java framework integration

Tags: java, android, frameworks, constructor

I'm Developing an Android Package.

I'm trying to integrate a Framework(AQuery) into my project.

I'm always getting this error. Is there any work around for this?

Please refer to the screenshot:

http://s7.postimg.org/jxbuxkojv/Pics_Art_1371463536409.jpg

Comment: Please post text, not links to images.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass `Context` of your activity . if you declaring it  in an initialiser  or innerclass use `YOURCLASSNAME.this` instead of `this`

for example :

```
AQuery aq= new AQuery(MyActivity.this)
```